# 15. The numbers are of type DWORD and the product (8EB50h - 290ADCFFh )*2939Ah = N16 =

Tags: assembly, hex

15. The numbers are of type DWORD and the product

`(8EB50h - 290ADCFFh )*2939Ah = N16 =`

Can someone please explain how to subtract in DWORD hexadecimal?

I am wondering because when I subtract normally, I get a negative number. But I am not allowed to have a negative number as an answer.

Comment: Same way as in any base. Or, if you are not comfortable, then convert to decimal, perform the operation and convert back.

Comment: I am wondering because when I subtract normally, I get a negative number. But I am not allowed to have a negative number as an answer.

Comment: 290ADCFF is clearly a lot larger than 8EB50, so the subtraction will result in a negative.

Comment: I have to convert to a non negative number somehow, which is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Negative numbers are represented as [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), which in short means you need to add 2^32 to your negative result and convert that.

Comment: Subtraction with fixed-width integers wraps around by borrowing from the non-existent next higher bit.  So a `sub` instruction on x86 with those inputs would set the carry flag (`CF`).  See [this nice guide to carry/overflow in binary math](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt), with nice 4-bit examples.  (linked from [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), which has lots of good links).

Answer (score 1):

This link may be of use [Hexadecimal Arithmetic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/hexadecimal_arithmetic.htm). Which states:

> Hexadecimal Subtraction
>
> The subtraction of hexadecimal numbers follow the same rules as the
>   subtraction of numbers in any other number system. The only variation
>   is in borrowed number. In the decimal system, you borrow a group of
>   10(base 10). In the binary system, you borrow a group of 10(base 2).
>   In the hexadecimal system you borrow a group of 10(base 16).

4A6 - 1BC

6 - C, need to borrow 10, so effectively 16 - C = **A**.

4A0 - borrowed 10 = 490, so effectively now 49 - 1B.

9 - B, need to
   borrow 10, so effectively 19 - B = **E**.

40 - borrowed 10 = 30, so
   effectively now 3 - 1 = **2**. So answer = **2EA**.

Comment: Personally I have ancient Casio FX-45M calculator. Covers Binary, Hex and Octal.

Comment: `0x4A6 - 0x1BC` is `0x2ea`.  Your steps are right; it looks like just a typo.

Comment: @PeterCordes, sorry about that corrected and now off to the opticians :)